# How did wolfram simplify this integral?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, measure-theory

I am computing a convolution $e^{-ax^2}*e^{-bx^2}$. The integral is of course $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-a(x-w)^2 - bw^2}dw$, and I have simplified this down to
$$\sqrt{\pi}\frac{e^{-x^2\frac{ab}{a+b}}}{\sqrt{a+b}}\bigg{(} 1+\text{erf}\big{(} \frac{ax}{\sqrt{a+b}}\big{)}\bigg{)} $$
this calculation can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/363304/convolution-computation-involving-e-x2). Also, putting that integral into wolfram alpha gives the same answer.
BUT when I give wolfram alpha the command convolution$(e^{-ax^2}, e^{-bx^2})$ it returns
$$\sqrt{\pi}\frac{e^{-x^2\frac{ab}{a+b}}}{\sqrt{a+b}} $$
Where is this value coming from/ why does it differ from the integral?

Comment: Your first integral (with the error function) is incorrect.  Check your math.

Comment: even wolfram alpha computes the integral the same, ill add that

Comment: The example had the range $0$ to $\infty$ and you are using $-\infty$ to $\infty$.  Could that be the problem?

Comment: @WADon the function is symmetric about the y-axis, so going from -infinity to infinity is just double going from 0 to infinity

Comment: Not so in this case - the presence of the $x$ component breaks the symmetry, $(x-w)^2$ is no the same as $(x+w)^2$.

Comment: @WADon ahh yes that is true. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is the [Gaussian integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral)
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-c(t+d)^2}\,dt=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{c}} $$
and note that
$$-a(x-w)^2-bw^2=-(a+b)\left(w-\frac{ax}{a+b}\right)^2-\frac{abx^2}{a+b} $$

Comment: Okay perfect, I see where my error was now. Thank you!